# Does the H1 chip (in Airpods 2 and PBP) support streaming from one device to two sets of earphones?

Tags: airpods

I remember reading somewhere that the new H1 chip supports streaming to two sets of earphones simultaneously from a single device.

That is, you can have one source device that's playing audio, and two sets of airpods would be able to hear that audio at the same time.

Is this a feature of the H1 chip?

Comment: Is this about whether the chip supports this in general, or whether iOS supports it? Keep in mind that the streaming originates on the iDevice/Mac, not on the Airpods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re referring to [Airplay 2](https://www.apple.com/airplay/), which now allows compatible devices to Airplay to multiple devices (such as both your HomePod and your Smart TV).

AirPods use Bluetooth, so this does not apply unfortunately (Airplay uses Wi-Fi).

Comment: Yes, that's what I remember reading.

Answer (score 0):

With today's announcement of iOS 13, Apple will support streaming to two sets of Airpods from a single device. No mention of whether the H1 chip is required or not.

> Shared listening
>
> Pair two sets of AirPods to one iPhone and enjoy the same song or movie along with a friend.

[Source](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13-preview/features/)